# How to create a new record and open a page in APEX 5

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to bind an "Execute PL/SQL Code" to a button using Dynamic Actions then open a page using the new ID (execid)

```
begin
insert into SMIG_EXECUTION(EXECNAME, CALL, STEPID, DURATIONMIN)
values('bla bla',REPLACE(:P31_CALLTEMPLATE,'#STEPID#',to_char(:P31_STEPID)), :P31_STEPID, 0)

returning execid into :P31_NEWEXECID ;
end;
```

The PL/SQL code is working, but I can't shake the link to opening the new page as a Dynamic Action and passing that new value as P2_EXECID.

[image]

Comment: where is the code/link for opening new page?

Comment: Thanks Simon, you've asked the question I'm asking. If I know where it is, I wouldn't need to ask. How can I open a page using a Dynamic Action ?

Comment: In what way do you want to "open a new page"? Just navigate to a detail page with the new id? Or are you talking about a modal dialog?

Comment: I want to open a page AFTER the 2 Dynamic Actions above. I don't see any Dynamic Action to open a page. The EXECUTE button, can hold either {Submit Page, Redirect to Page in this application or Defined by Dynamic Action} My button is define with the later. But I also want to open a page which led to beleive I can't do both because I don't have any Open Page in dynamic Action.

Comment: I just don't understand why you want to "open" a new page after running DA's. What's wrong with using a branch?

Comment: I would love to branch. How can I branch using Dynamic Actions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using window.open() (javascript function)

open() method opens a new browser window.

- > Add TRUE ACTION to your existing Dynamic Action
- > Choose EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT CODE for your Action
- > Then paste this code:

  ```
  window.open('f?p='+$v('pFlowId')+':'+$v('pFlowStepId')+':'+$v('pFlowInstance')+'::::<page item here>:<value of the item to be passed>:','_self');
  ```

Note:
 $v('pFlowId') => APPLICATION ID
 $v('pFlowStepId') => PAGE NUMBER
 $v('pFlowInstance') => SESSION ID

- If multiple items/values needs to be passed, you can do that by listing the items/values with a comma as a delimeter

  **i.e. 'f?p=.....:P2_ITEM1,P2_ITEM2,P2_ITEM3:1,2,3:';**

EDIT: added second parameter

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. And I would not want to open a new window so I'm trying to find another alternative.

Comment: can you post here what you have done in your dynamic action?open methods' second parameter lets you decide where you want to open the url (main page, new tab or new window).